# Concatenate results from a SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, concatenation

I have data like this in a table

```
NAME PRICE
A    2
B    3
C    5
D    9
E    5
```

I want to display all the values in one row; for instance:

```
A,2|B,3|C,5|D,9|E,5|
```

How would I go about making a query that will give me a string like this in Oracle? I don't need it to be programmed into something; I just want a way to get that line to appear in the results so I can copy it over and paste it in a word document.

My Oracle version is 10.2.0.5.

Comment: copy and paste it into another word?

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Release 2: 10.2.0.5

Comment: +1 for the question, this is beyond `listagg`....

Comment: @bonCodigo; the OP can't use LISTAGG() as this isn't 11g, however, it's not beyond the capabilities: `select listagg(name || ',' || price, '|') within group ( order by name ) from TABLE`

Comment: @Ben thanks for sharing that. Well I followed a different path with `Xmlagg` as I was using 11g. Any thoughts to improve it..

Comment: SOLVED:
I just exported the values to CSV file and then created a program to concatenate and output to another file with that format... LOL thanks for trying to help though guys

Answer (score 13, accepted):

-- Oracle 10g --

```
SELECT deptno, WM_CONCAT(ename) AS employees
  FROM   scott.emp
GROUP BY deptno;

Output:
     10  CLARK,MILLER,KING
     20  SMITH,FORD,ADAMS,SCOTT,JONES
     30  ALLEN,JAMES,TURNER,BLAKE,MARTIN,WARD
```

Comment: This works beautifully, plus it's easy to remember how to use. You can throw out duplicates with `WM_CONCAT(distinct ename)`, though I doubt you can sort them. And, unfortunately, it's not [officially documented](http://psoug.org/definition/wm_concat.htm).

Comment: the question was different

Answer (score 15):

I know this is a little late but try this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT(CONCAT(NAME,','),PRICE),'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) AS CONCATDATA
FROM your_table
```

Comment: The OP was on 10g and `listagg()` was introduced in 11g.  But this answer makes the whole post a better round up of string aggregation techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I need something like that quickly and I want to stay on SQL without using PL/SQL, I use something similar to the hack below:

```
select sys_connect_by_path(col, ', ') as concat
from
(
  select 'E' as col, 1 as seq from dual
  union
  select 'F', 2 from dual
  union
  select 'G', 3 from dual
)
where seq = 3
start with seq = 1
connect by prior seq+1 = seq
```

It's a hierarchical query which uses the "sys_connect_by_path" special function, which is designed to get the "path" from a parent to a child.

What we are doing is simulating that the record with seq=1 is the parent of the record with seq=2 and so fourth, and then getting the full path of the last child (in this case, record with seq = 3), which will effectively be a concatenation of all the "col" columns

Adapted to your case:

```
select sys_connect_by_path(to_clob(col), '|') as concat
from
(
  select name || ',' || price as col, rownum as seq, max(rownum) over (partition by 1) as max_seq
  from
  (
   /* Simulating your table */
    select 'A' as name, 2 as price from dual
    union
    select 'B' as name, 3 as price from dual
    union
    select 'C' as name, 5 as price from dual
    union
    select 'D' as name, 9 as price from dual
    union
    select 'E' as name, 5 as price from dual
  )
)
where seq = max_seq
start with seq = 1
connect by prior seq+1 = seq
```

Result is: `|A,2|B,3|C,5|D,9|E,5`

Answer (score 2):

As you're in Oracle 10g you can't use the excellent `listagg()`. However, there are numerous other [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

There's no particular need for all the complicated stuff. Assuming the following table

```
create table a ( NAME varchar2(1), PRICE number);
insert all
into a values ('A',    2)
into a values ('B',    3)
into a values ('C',    5)
into a values ('D',    9)
into a values ('E',    5)
select * from dual
```

The unsupported function `wm_concat` should be sufficient:

```
select replace(replace(wm_concat (name || '#' || price), ',', '|'), '#', ',')
  from a;

REPLACE(REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(NAME||'#'||PRICE),',','|'),'#',',')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A,2|B,3|C,5|D,9|E,5
```

But, you could also alter Tom Kyte's `stragg`, also in the above link, to do it without the replace functions.

Comment: you are using `wm_concat` great, do leave a comment on my answer as well please.

Comment: i will test yours in a bit

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, using `model` clause:

```
-- sample of data from your question
with t1(NAME1, PRICE) as(
   select 'A',    2 from dual union all
   select 'B',    3 from dual union all
   select 'C',    5 from dual union all
   select 'D',    9 from dual union all
   select 'E',    5 from dual
) -- the query
 select Res
  from (select name1
             , price
             , rn
             , res
         from t1
         model
         dimension by (row_number() over(order by name1) rn)
         measures (name1, price, cast(null as varchar2(101)) as res)
         (res[rn] order by rn desc = name1[cv()] || ',' || price[cv()] || '|' ||  res[cv() + 1])
       )
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
RES
----------------------
A,2|B,3|C,5|D,9|E,5|
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a4df/4)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following, which is grossly inefficient and untested.

```
    create function foo returning varchar2  as  
    (    
        declare bar varchar2(8000) --arbitrary number
        CURSOR cur IS
        SELECT name,price  
        from my_table  
        LOOP

    FETCH cur INTO r;

    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

       bar:= r.name|| ',' ||r.price || '|'

  END LOOP;  
  dbms_output.put_line(bar);
       return bar
    )
```

Comment: what does  `FETCH cur INTO r;` do?

Comment: places the results of the `cursor` defined as `cur` into a variable called `r`.  Notice how i concat `bar` and reference your columns via `r.name` and `r.price`

Comment: When i make that function, how do i execute it? Do i just run that function in the sql query window?

Comment: @Ramie in sql developer you can right click and run the function.

Comment: Can i change the number inside the varchar2, because i ran your query and it says that its finished executing but no results.
    create function f323oo returning varchar2  as  
    (    
        declare bar varchar2(8000) --arbitrary number
        CURSOR cur IS
        SELECT CURRENCY, ONE  
        from mkt.view_me
        LOOP

    FETCH cur INTO r;

    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

       bar:= r.CURRENCY|| ',' ||r.ONE || '|'

       END LOOP;
       return bar
    )

Comment: @Ramie you may change the number to I believe to `65536` as a maximum.  If it doesn't return into anything try the code I just posted.  I added a `dbms_output.put_line` which is equivalent to a system print.

Comment: it didn't work as it showed up with an empty result, sorry :(

Comment: But works in any version +1

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get till here using xmlagg: using oracle 11G from sql fiddle.

Data Table:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
1       0       0
1       1       1
2       0       0
3       0       0
3       1       0


SELECT
    RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      XMLAgg(XMLElement("x", col1,',', col2, col3)

ORDER BY col1), '<x>'), '</x>', '|')) AS COLS
  FROM ab
;
```

Results:

```
COLS
1,00| 3,00| 2,00| 1,11| 3,10|
```

### * [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bfd9a/26)

- [Reference to read on XMLAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm)

Comment: @Woot4Moo that's why I said I only managed to get till here. I didn't post for an upvote but for another method if possible to adapot. However didn't expect a downvote... :$

Comment: Such is life I suppose.  I felt it was down vote worthy, as it doesn't provide much detail around `XMLAgg` and how this is efficient

Comment: @WootMoo I Don't think it's my answer is wrong. I have just missed out `|` as a separator. I am using different sample data, but my logic is correct.

Comment: @Ramie please take a look at this answer. It does support `10g` as well. Performance wise it's pretty fast.

Comment: make it work with 2 columns and ill test it, that way i can just replace variables

Comment: @Ramie Good lord! just remove col3 from the xmlelement! [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bfd9a/27)

Comment: @Ramie all good so far at your side? Since I was challenged....here I have gotten to test this with many heavy machines. It runs very well. Looking forward to hear from you. And let me know if you need further clarifications or changes ;)