# How do I simulate 'LISTAGG' functionality in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, listagg

`orig_system` has `DNB` as value, and they have lot of `owner_table_id` associated to `DNB`. Ii am trying to bring all the IDs from multiple row to a single row.

But Oracle 10g does not support `listagg`. Is there any other way to concatenate all `OWNER_TABLE_ID` in a single row for DNB.

Below is the query used:

```
SELECT OWNER_TABLE_ID,LISTAGG (ORIG_SYSTEM,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORIG_SYSTEM)
   from APPS.HZ_ORIG_SYS_REFERENCES
   WHERE ROWNUM < 100 GROUP BY OWNER_TABLE_ID
```

Below is the sample data:

```
OWNER_TABLE_ID, ORIG_SYSTEM
182403  DNB
16604   DNB
84818   DNB
172891  DNB
16605   DNB
84819   DNB
205544  DNB
16606   DNB
84820   DNB
```

Expected result:

```
ORIG_SYSTEM OWNER_TABLE_ID,
DNB         182403,16604,84818,72891,16605,84819,205544,16606,84820"
```

Comment: May be you need to `GROUP BY` something other than `OWNER_TABLE_ID`?

Comment: An entire collection of approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243131/concatenate-results-from-a-sql-query-in-oracle

Comment: See [**Oracle String Aggregation Techniques**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/category/oracle-string-aggregation/)

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I took a look at your solutions. The hierarchical query solution is very close to what I posted. There are two differences - I don't understand why you needed both a `row_number()` and a lagged copy (when you can compare `rn` and `prior rn` with simple arithmetic), and why you have that complicated way of extracting only the full path when `connect_by_isleaf` serves exactly that purpose. Or... **disregard** the second question; `connect_by_isleaf` is Oracle 10 and your solution was for Oracle 9. The OP here is on Oracle 10 though.

Comment: @mathguy I have to elaborate the query every time I post it as askers request. So, I have no choice but to keep the query a bit elaborated. I can write a query to show what LISTAGG does internally, and you will say what is the need to write a huge query when LISTAGG could do it in single level. I haven't posted the query as an answer since I wanted OP to do it himself and these are FAQs and there are plenty of similar Q/As across the board.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I don't see how any of what you said has anything to do with my question. I asked why you needed two `row_number()`s, one current and one lagged, instead of writing the condition like I did. What's that got to do with anything you said? Other than that, after I posted I saw all the pointers to old solutions and I didn't find the one I came up with (yours was the closest). If you can point me to where the solution I offered is suggested, I will be grateful and I will withdraw my answer.

Comment: @mathguy Why would you withdraw your answer. It is fine. And yes, no need to use row_number twice in 10g. It is for 9i which is mentioned in the article.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I often withdraw my answers when I find they had already been posted (either under the same question or three years ago) - sometimes with a quick note to say I had an answer but withdrew it because it is a duplicate of ... (with a link). Keeping the site clean. In this case, I looked at the various answers given over time and I didn't see 'my' solution being offered (although as I mentioned yours came close - but since you targeted Oracle 9, `connect_by_isleaf` wasn't available and I think that is a bigger difference than how `row_number()` is used).

Comment: NP.. have tried another query and that works fine. but it ends up with error message ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small 19011. 00000 - "Character string buffer too small" *Cause: The string result asked for is too big to return back *Action: Get the result as a lob instead............. i am able to get 75000 records only out of 1500000 records. and the above error message......

Comment: this is the current query i am using ...........SELECT OWNER_TABLE_ID,RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE( XMLAgg(XMLElement("x",ORIG_SYSTEM,',') ORDER BY ORIG_SYSTEM), '<x>'), '</x>')) AS OWNER_TABLE_IDs FROM APPS.HZ_ORIG_SYS_REFERENCES group by OWNER_TABLE_ID

Comment: @Dheerdhanraj - please explain "works fine, but ends up with error" - I don't understand.

Comment: i mean, when i run the query its gives the output but stops at 75000 record count.. there are 1500000 records and i am unable to fetch all records..due to rror message ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small 19011. 00000 - "Character string buffer too small" *Cause: The string result asked for is too big to return back *Action: Get the result as a lob instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a hierarchical query (with all the bells and whistles) and the analytic function `row_number()` - both available in Oracle 10. NOTE: the `partition by` clause is needed if you have more than one `ORIG_SYSTEM`; I ordered the `OWNER_TABLE_ID`'s by `null` (which means "randomly"), but you can order them by something as needed (for example, by themselves, in either increasing or decreasing order - there was no such order visible in your example though).

```
with
     hz_orig_sys_references ( owner_table_id, orig_system ) as (
       select 182403, 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 16604 , 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 84818 , 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 172891, 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 16605 , 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 84819 , 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 205544, 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 16606 , 'DNB' from dual union all
       select 84820 , 'DNB' from dual
     ),
     prep ( owner_table_id, orig_system, rn ) as (
       select owner_table_id, orig_system, 
              row_number() over (partition by orig_system order by null)
       from   hz_orig_sys_references
     )
select orig_system, 
       ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(owner_table_id, ','), ',')  as owner_tables
from   prep     
where  connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by orig_system = prior orig_system and rn = prior rn + 1
start with rn = 1;

ORIG_SYSTEM  OWNER_TABLES
------------ ----------------------------------------------------------
DNB          182403,16604,84818,172891,84820,84819,205544,16606,16605
```

Comment: Thanks.. the data i provided is just a sample data we have more then one ORIG_SYSTEM and more than 1000 OWNER_TABLES_id. the above query did not work. is their a any other solution.. ..with oracle 11 g is very easy but oracle 10 g i m unable to do.

Comment: "Did not work" is not very helpful. What didn't work? I intentionally wrote the query in a way to allow for more than one `ORIG_SYSTEM`, was there a problem with that? More likely, you ended up with strings more than 4000 characters long, which means you need to work with CLOBs. But it is best if you tell us all what the issues where instead of us guessing.

Comment: NP.. have tried another query and that works fine. but it ends up with error message

Comment: NP.. have tried another query and that works fine. but it ends up with error message ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead............. i am able to get 75000 records only out of 1500000 records. and the above error message......

Comment: this is the current query i am using ...........SELECT  OWNER_TABLE_ID,RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      XMLAgg(XMLElement("x",ORIG_SYSTEM,',') 
ORDER BY ORIG_SYSTEM), '<x>'), '</x>')) AS OWNER_TABLE_IDs
  FROM APPS.HZ_ORIG_SYS_REFERENCES
group by OWNER_TABLE_ID

Comment: You are trying to create a string that is longer than 4000 characters (the maximum for varchar2). Which begs the question: WHY are you trying to do this in the first place? Almost surely the solution you came up with (concatenate all the owner_tables into a huge comma-separated string) is not the correct solution.