# Combining SQL rows in just one row (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm using an Oracle Database on PL/SQL Developer, and I want to combine the resulted rows of my query in just one row.

I have this:

```
   Column 1
1. Row 1
2. Row 2
3. Row 3
```

I want this:

```
   Column 1
1. Row 1, Row 2, Row 3
```

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT produto.ds_produto || ' Lote ->' || itmvto_estoque.cd_lote || 'Validade ->' || itmvto_estoque.dt_validade
FROM  itmvto_estoque, mvto_estoque, produto, atendime
WHERE itmvto_estoque.cd_mvto_estoque = mvto_estoque.cd_mvto_estoque
AND   produto.cd_produto = itmvto_estoque.cd_produto
AND   mvto_estoque.cd_atendimento = 1532174
AND   produto.cd_especie = 1
```

The database version is 10.

I found some similar questions here ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558509/concatenate-and-group-multiple-rows-in-oracle)), but all of them are a little different, because I need to do it in just one column.

**EDIT:** The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243131/concatenate-results-from-a-sql-query-in-oracle) for example used two columns and resulted more than one row.

Comment: you should try to make your sample query relevant to your sample data. Your query as posted is quite painful to read.

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609917/listagg-alternative-in-oracle-10g

Comment: Not exactly, the example used two columns and resulted more than one row with group by. I need one column and one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have at least Oracle 11, you will not be able to use `LISTAGG`. Therefore, one alternative would be using `XMLAGG`, like this:

```
select 
rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, column1, ', ')).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ',')
from your_table
```

Note that this probably does not work if some form of group by is necessary, but it will help to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use a group by, nevertheless I got no result with this:

                   `SELECT DISTINCT 
rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, produto.ds_produto || ' Lote ->' || itmvto_estoque.cd_lote || 'Validade ->' || itmvto_estoque.dt_validade, ', ')).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ',')
FROM  itmvto_estoque, mvto_estoque, produto, atendime`

Comment: I wont be able to help you on that query if you do not provide table structure.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, the PIVOT function in PL /SQL did not appear until Oracle 11g.

The following article provides some options more succinctly than I could.

http://oraclecoder.com/tutorials/three-ways-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-oracle-sql--160

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I can't take credit though, I found it here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171997/how-to-obtain-the-functionality-of-listagg-function-in-oracle-10g

```
SQL> with tbl(col1) as (
     select 'Row 1' from dual union all
     select 'Row 2' from dual union all
     select 'Row 3' from dual
   )
   SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (col1, ', '), 3) col1
         FROM (SELECT col1 , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY col1 ) rn,
                      COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
                 FROM tbl)
        WHERE rn = cnt
   START WITH rn = 1
   CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1;

COL1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Row 1, Row 2, Row 3
```